# Include file contents in script PHP

Tags: php, file

Real simple one for someone. I've forgotten the terminology, so I'm having trouble finding a question I'm sure has already been answered.

I'd like to read the contents of a file that's included in the script itself eg.

```
<php
// NOTE: code is not correct, just illustrative.
// read 'file' data at end of script
$inlineFile = fopen(___FILE_HERE___,"r");
while ($rec = fgetcsv("\t", $inlineFile)) {
    // process file record
}
__FILE_HERE__
zzz 123 5445
aab 494 2983
__END_OF_FILE
?>
```

What is this technique officially called (eg. 'In-line data?') - if I know the term, I'll be off and away coding it I'm sure.
UPDATE: I did find inline data eg.

```
$dutyCodesInline=<<<END
AL  Annual Leave    LEAVE_ANNUAL    LEAVE
BL  Long Service Leave  LEAVE_LSL   LEAVE
UW  Unworked Workers Comp.  LEAVE_OTHER LEAVE
END;
```

but my preference is to read the data as if it were a file (because one day it will probably be a file).

Comment: Why not make a real file? If it could be a file in the future, why not do it now?

Comment: Because I want to keep the data and the file together, for ease of modification. It's not a big deal, but if it can be done I want to do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot treat a part of a file like you wish to.

You can use heredoc syntax for now, like this :

```
$data = <<<END
...
END;
```

Later you replace this code  by :

```
$data = file_get_contents ( $filename );
```

Comment: Thanks Lorenz, I began to suspect as much.